# Manipulating Date/time with JS and moment

Tags: javascript, datetime, momentjs

I have 2 dates and I need to create a 3rd date using those 2 dates.

```
if (document.getElementById("endDate"))
endDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;

if (document.getElementById("presentDate"))
presentDate = document.getElementById("presentDate").value;
```

If `Present date = "12/5/2018"` and `End date = "12/25/2018"` then my  `New date  = "12/26/2018";`

Since, JavaScript date months range from 0-11 and also the dates are kind of messy, I am not getting the desired results.

What I tried:

```
var presentDt = new Date(presentDate);
var endDt = new Date(endDate);

var newDay = endDt.getUTCDate()+1; 
var presentMonth = presentDt.getUTCMonth();
var presentYear = presentDt.getUTCFullYear();
var nextDate= presentMonth + '/' + endDay + '/' + presentYear;
```

- Issue 1: This above code works but if my `endDate` is on the 31st, then adding `UTCDate+1` makes it 32, which returns invalid date.
- Issue 2: If I do `UTCMonth()`, it returns 11 but if I want to add 2 months then it returns 13 which is also invalid. The issue is basically that I am not able to manipulate the dates as I want.

I also tried moment, however I am having similar issues and I am not able to manipulate the dates easily as I want them to.

Also tried `getDate` and `getMonth` but it does the same thing.

Is there a better way of handling the overall date/time with JavaScript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is what i did:

First i created the following functions to look at the number of days and months.

```
 function formattedDate(date) {
        var day = date.getDate();
        var monthIndex = date.getMonth();
        var year = date.getFullYear();

        return (monthIndex + 1) + '/' + day + '/' + year;
    }
    function myNewDate(datestring) {
        var dates = datestring.split("/");
        var year, month, day;
        if (dates.length < 3) {
            dates = datestring.split("-");
            year = dates[0];
            month = dates[1] - 1;
            day = dates[2];
        } else  {
            year = dates[2];
            month = dates[0] - 1;
            day = dates[1];
        }


        var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30 ,31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
        // Overflow day
        if (day > days[month])
            day = days[month];

        return new Date(year, month, day);
    }
    function newDate(date1, date2) {
        var days = [31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31];
        var year = date1.getFullYear();
        var month = date1.getMonth() + 1;
        var day = date2.getDate() + 1;


        // Check leap year
        if ((year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || year % 400 == 0)
            days[1] = 29;

        // Overflow day
        if (day > days[month])
            day = days[month];

        var newdate = new Date(year, month, day);

        return newdate;
    }
```

Here, i used the above function to create my new date. You can also add/subtract days/months as you want by updating the above.

```
        var mpresent = myNewDate(presentDate);
        var mstart = myNewDate(startDate);
        var myDate =  (formattedDate(newDate(mpresent, mstart)));
```

Answer (score 0):

**1: add/subtract days:**
    new Date(new Date().setDate(new Date().getDay() + 3))

**2: add/subtract months:**
    new Date(new Date().setMonth(new Date().getMonth() + 3))

```
//your code
var presentDt = new Date(presentDate);
var endDt = new Date(endDate);

var newDay = new Date(new Date().setDate(endDt.getDay() + 2)); 
var presentMonth = presentDt.getUTCMonth();
var presentYear = presentDt.getUTCFullYear();
```

Comment: This is really confusing. Can you please add a description as well. Thank you.

Comment: if you want to add 2 days :
new Date(new Date().setDate(endDt.getDay() + 2));

Comment: This  only adds months and days separately. I need to create a new Date using both +1day and +1 month. The issue here is that once i do it separately and then use getUTC again, it doesn't work anymore.

Comment: var currentDate = new Date();
    console.log('currentDate :', currentDate.toUTCString());
    var oneDayPlusCurrentDate = new Date(new Date().setDate(currentDate.getDay() + 3))
    console.log('currentDate + 1 day:', oneDayPlusCurrentDate.toUTCString());
    var oneMonthPlus_withoneDayPlusCurrentDate = new Date(oneDayPlusCurrentDate.setMonth(oneDayPlusCurrentDate.getMonth() + 1));
    console.log('currentDate + 1 day + 1 month:', oneMonthPlus_withoneDayPlusCurrentDate.toUTCString());

Comment: for above code, response here:
//currentDate : Thu, 06 Dec 2018 05:35:05 GMT
//currentDate + 1 day: Fri, 07 Dec 2018 05:35:05 GMT
//currentDate + 1 day + 1 month: Mon, 07 Jan 2019 05:35:05 GMT

Comment: I am trying to create a new date using 2 dates. this is just adding 1 day to 1 date from above.

Answer (score 0):

Since your input string is not in a format recognized by `new Date()` across environments, I suggest to use [`moment(String, String)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/) to parse it.

Then you can use [`moment(Object)`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/object/), moment's setters (like [`year()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/year/), [`month()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/month/) and [`date()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/get-set/date/)) and [`format()`](http://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/) to get the desired output.

Here a live sample:

```js
var presentDt = "12/5/2018";
var endDt = "12/25/2018";

// Parse your input with momentjs
var mPresent = moment(presentDt, "MM/DD/YYYY");
var mEnd = moment(endDt, "MM/DD/YYYY");

// Create a new momnt object compliant with your needs
var nextDate = moment({
  year: mPresent.year(), // get presentDt's year
  month: mPresent.month(), // get presentDt's month
  date: mEnd.add(1, 'day').date() // get endDt day of the month and add 1 day to it
});

// Display the result in the format you need
console.log(nextDate.format("MM/DD/YYYY"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
```

Note that you will get `01` as day result when `endDt` represents the last day of the month.

Comment: This is returning NAN. Do i need to add some library besides what i already have? It's working on this console but not in my machine.

Comment: Which moment version are you using? No need to use other library, the snippet works using only momentjs (v2.22.2)

Comment: I have the same one you're using but it says Invalid date.

Comment: Could it be because i am picking the date from a date picker? It makes no sense. It just doesn't seem to work in my local machine

Comment: So i updated moment(presentDt) .format( "MM/DD/YYYY"); and it returns the value but nextDate is not being set.

Comment: I'm sorry but I can't fully understand which is your issue, I suggest to provide  [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Examples](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to show your problem in order to get more relevant help.