# Date difference issue in moment

Tags: javascript, momentjs, datetimepicker, moment-timezone

I am trying to create a new Date using 2 dates I have. Basically my new date

`Output:`

```
 Date 1 = (presentdate +1 month , endDate+1 day, presentdate+1 year);


            //Example 1: 
            var presentDate = "11/12/2018";
            var endDate = "2/8/2018";
            var Dat1 = "12/9/2018"; //new date

           //Example 2 :
            var presentDate = "11/12/2018";
            var endDate = "5/25/2018";
            var Dat1 = "12/26/2018"; //new date

          //Example 3 :
            var presentDate = "1/5/2018";
            var endDate = "5/30/2018";
            var Date1 = "2/31/2018"; // invalid date
            //should've been 2/28/2018 since that is the last day of the month

         //Example 4:
            var presentDate = "3/5/2018";
            var endDate = "10/30/2018";
            var Date1 = "4/31/2018"; //Invalid date. Should've been 4/30/2019 since it's last day of the month
```

My code:

```
            var mPresent = moment(presentDt);
            var mEnd = moment(eDt);

            var Date1 = moment({
            year: mPresent.year(), // get presentDt's year
            month: mPresent.add(1, 'month').month(), // get presentDt's month
            date: mStart.date() // get startdt day of the month
        });

console.log(Date1);
```

It doesn't work in all cases because not every month have 30,31 days and then there is the leap year. I need to create a date that is valid because in some of these cases it returns invalid date.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: Did you try `mPresent = moment(presentDt)`?

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes. I tried different formats but nothing seems to work. And it's weird because it works in the console only when it's declared directly. Maybe it's think it's an issue with datepicker format.

Comment: Did you try to call moment without any explicit format? How do you define your date pickers? Please show the relevant HTML tags.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yes i did. I have it in my code. Just updated it.

Comment: FWIW, `<input type=date>` uses ISO format for its value. As for your question, I'm not sure what the problem is or how to fix it.

Comment: if it works in console...maybe not a issue of javascript libraries, is an order to load javascript files

Comment: @Sk. I updated my question. That's was the main issue here.

Comment: you can writte the cases a little more clearly, like case a , result an desired result, case b .. and case c ..etc

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Manipulating Date/time with JS and moment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53639554/manipulating-date-time-with-js-and-moment)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure what's going on with your code, but I chopped out most of it and basically did a 1-liner to calculate the # of months difference - seems to work.

```js
document.querySelector("#ok").addEventListener("click", function () {
  var paymentDate = document.getElementById("presentDate").value;
  var etDate = document.getElementById("endDate").value;

  var RemainingPayments = moment(etDate).diff(moment(paymentDate), 'months');
  console.log(RemainingPayments);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.22.2/moment.min.js"></script>
<label>Present date</label><input id="presentDate" name="presentDate"  type="date">
<label>End Date</label> <input id="endDate" name="endDate" type="date">
<button id='ok'>OK</button>
```